# Eclipse, svn:externals, hide externals from project explorer

Tags: eclipse, svn, hide, explorer, externals

I'm using Eclipse Indigo IDE + Subversive SVN plugin.
The project I'm working on includes a lot of files and directories (150+) from an other project in the SVN repository using SVN:externals.
Because there are so many files from the other project it is a bit complicated to determine which files are externals and which do really belong to the current project.

The question is, is it possible to hide (filter out) the external files from the Eclipse Package Explorer?

I already tried to do so by using the "Filters..." option of the Package Explorer, but wasn't able to figure out if a file is an externals, because that information is not stored in the file itself.

Thanks in advance!